# How to use rgbif to download occurrence data from multiple polygons at once?

Tags: r, ropensci

I am trying to download occurrence data of multiple taxonomic groups from multiple regions using the R package `rgbif`. I prefer to have one download by combining all the regions together (because I have thousands of regions, it would be insane to have separate downloads). However, I did not find a way to do so. I can do `occ_download` for one region per query.

Here are my exemplary code:

```r
library(rgbif)
gbif_taxon_keys = c(212, 359)
# below are bbox of 3 regions;
# I have polygons as WKT, but they are clockwise 
# (how to convert to counter clockwise??)
wkts = c("POLYGON((11.3431 47.2451,11.4638 47.2451,11.4638 47.2919,11.3431 47.2919,11.3431 47.2451))",
"POLYGON((12.9644 47.7608,13.0922 47.7608,13.0922 47.8453,12.9644 47.8453,12.9644 47.7608))",
"POLYGON((14.2284 48.2217,14.3669 48.2217,14.3669 48.3443,14.2284 48.3443,14.2284 48.2217))")

# this works
queries = occ_download_prep(
  pred_in("taxonKey", gbif_taxon_keys),
  pred("hasCoordinate", TRUE),
  pred("hasGeospatialIssue", FALSE),
  pred_within(wkts[1]),
  user = gbif_user, pwd = gbif_pwd,
  email = gbif_email)
out_test = occ_download_queue(.list = list(queries))

# now try to combine regions in one download
# this does not work
queries = occ_download_prep(
  pred_in("taxonKey", gbif_taxon_keys),
  pred("hasCoordinate", TRUE),
  pred("hasGeospatialIssue", FALSE),
  pred_within(wkts),
  user = gbif_user, pwd = gbif_pwd,
  email = gbif_email)
out_test = occ_download_queue(.list = list(queries))
```

```
Error: 'value' must be length 1
```

```r
# this does not work neither (it runs though)
queries = occ_download_prep(
  pred_in("taxonKey", gbif_taxon_keys),
  pred("hasCoordinate", TRUE),
  pred("hasGeospatialIssue", FALSE),
  pred("geometry", paste0(wkts, collapse = ";")),
  user = gbif_user, pwd = gbif_pwd,
  email = gbif_email)
out_test = occ_download_queue(.list = list(queries))
```

```
<<gbif download metadata>>
  Status: KILLED
```

From my download center on GBIF, it says "The download request was unsuccessful. ".

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: `rgbif` maintainer here. i'll get to this soon - on leave so may take a while

Comment: Thanks @sckott ! Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I know it'll be ugly and maybe frowned upon, but maybe loop over `wkts` ? Sounds like there is something in the function that doesn't allow you to download more than one data set at a time. Or - you're exceeding the download limits? (not sure what/ how much data you are trying to get and whether the function creates separate downloads/requests? See "Occurrence Download Limits" on https://www.gbif.org/developer/occurrence#download)

Comment: Thanks @Geraldine I sure can loop over `wkts` but with over 10k of them, this will result in over 10k downloads; and I don't want to do so. Ideally, if I can group them say by country, then I will just have hundreds of downloads by the end. I just don't know how to do this with `rgbif`, thus the question here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out how to do this. I just combined all polygons into a multipolygon and it seems works.

In another word, I just put the above 3 polygon into this:

```r
wkts2 = "MULTIPOLYGON (((11.3431 47.2451, 11.4638 47.2451, 11.4638 47.2919, 11.3431 47.2919, 11.3431 47.2451)), ((12.9644 47.7608, 13.0922 47.7608, 13.0922 47.8453, 12.9644 47.8453, 12.9644 47.7608)), ((14.2284 48.2217, 14.3669 48.2217, 14.3669 48.3443, 14.2284 48.3443, 14.2284 48.2217)))"
```

then, I run:

```r
queries = occ_download_prep(
  pred_in("taxonKey", gbif_taxon_keys),
  pred("hasCoordinate", TRUE),
  pred("hasGeospatialIssue", FALSE),
  pred_within(wkts2),
  user = gbif_user, pwd = gbif_pwd,
  email = gbif_email)
out_test = occ_download_queue(.list = list(queries))
```

It works for this example. @sckott may have better approaches.

Comment: I would make sure to check that your results don't have coordinates outside your individual polygons.

Comment: Thanks @sckott ! Do you have other suggestions? You mentioned that it can be complicated, curious to hear what do you think.

Comment: If the above approach is working for you then you're all set! As I said, I'd just make sure the query you are doing is getting records from the polygons you want

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenating the polygons into a multipolygon leads to overlaps, which aren't valid, and will lead to failing downloads.

Instead, use a GIS library to combine the polygons.  This is the first I found for R:

```
library(sf)
x = st_as_sfc("POLYGON((5.032 52.237, 5.426 52.237, 5.426 52.525, 5.032 52.525, 5.032 52.237))")
y = st_as_sfc("POLYGON((5.234 52.033, 5.546 52.033, 5.546 52.311, 5.234 52.311, 5.234 52.033))")
u = st_union(x, y)

st_as_text(u)
[1] "POLYGON ((5.032 52.525, 5.426 52.525, 5.426 52.311, 5.546 52.311, 5.546 52.033, 5.234 52.033, 5.234 52.237, 5.032 52.237, 5.032 52.525))"
```

A quick check on [Wicket](https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html) shows we now have an 8-sided polygon, which should work as the within predicate.

I think, using this, you can probably put all your polygons into a single download. The limit is 10,000 points in total for a single download.

Comment: Thanks @MattBlissett ! This is great, but then it comes with another problem I think. `st_union` will return a clockwise polygon while GBIF asks for counter-clockwise, right? Thoughts?

Comment: `st_as_text(st_reverse(u))`, but I don't know if this will be required in every case.